# Create or Update field in Django many-to-many-through model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-related-manager

I want to create_or_update in m-m through model field

This is my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In my **view.py** 
Below code is work perfectly fine

```
person_obj = Person.objects.get(id=1)
group_obj = Group.objects.get(id=1)
group_obj.add(person_obj, through_defaults={'is_featured': False, 'is_active': True})
```

Now  for same group_obj and person_obj I want to update `is_featured = True` in membership model.

How can i do that? I can do it by filtering Membership table and update fields but i guess it is not a good practice.
I wanted to do it by better solution.

I have tried with same line

```
group_obj.member.add(person_obj, through_defaults={'is_featured': True, 'is_active': True})
```

but it is not updating that field.

Comment: Why do you think "filtering Membership table and update fields" is not the right answer? On the contrary, that is exactly what you should do: `Membership.objects.filter(group=group_obj, person=person_obj).update(is_featured=True)`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  It will work. but I am searching for better way to do it like update_or_create.

Comment: @Somil: the problem is that you do not want `is_active` to be updated I think?

Comment: no , it depends on request data, if  is_active is present in  request  data then it should be update.

Comment: @Somil: given it is not in the request data, and the membership does *not* exist, then what should happen?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem request data is just like {'is_featured': True, 'is_active': True}

Comment: @Somil: I am trying to reproduce `group_obj.add(person_obj, .....)` but I get: `AttributeError: 'group_ob' object has no attribute 'add'` Did this really work as it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an [**`.update_or_create(..)`** call [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) on the `Membership` model:

```
Membership.objects.update_or_create(
    person_id=person_id,
    group_id=group_id,
    defaults={'is_active': True, 'is_featured': True}
)
```

Here it will thus make a query where it looks if there already exists a `Membership` object for the given *`person_id`* and *`group_id`*. If not, it will construct one, with as values for `is_active` and `is_featured` here `True` (as specified in the `defaults`). If the `Membership` object already exists, then it will *update* both `is_active` and `is_featured` to `True`.